# APACHE SPARK: Is it possible to generate the part files having similar sizes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-sql

I am new to SPARK. I am running a SPARK-SQL code that is generating 6000 part files in hdfs location. Out of these 6000 part files, around 1500 files have sizes around 100 MB, while others are considerably smaller that 100 MB(some are around 30MB & most are in kb's). I feel that this is unbalanced size ditribution is making my code slower, and some of the executors are getting lost because of high load on those executors. Is there any way to balance the load on executors to avoid executor loss?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the distribution of the key of your data.

As far as I know, you can only load-balance the key by yourself manually.

One posible solution is running a sample job to sample the cardinalities of your key, then build a partition table (by a load balancing algorithm, you can search for it) and pass it to your custom partitioner.

Answer (score 1):

You can repartition your data with without shuffling the data,coalesce use for decrease the number of partitions in the RDD to numPartitions.

Suppose you have 6000 partition 
Read your data from spark dataframe apply coalesce with number of partition which you want

```
 df.coalesce(5000)
```

and save again

```
 dataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(location)
```

Comment: Hi Gabber, I tried `coalesce` but it still produces irregular sized part files. I think coalesce only decreases the number of partitions(part files), and it doesn't have any control over the size of part files being generated. I wonder if  there any way to get similar sized part files while keeping same number of partitions

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered problems like this many times myself.  I call it the "unfair division of labor" problem.

You haven't included many details about the application.  One source of problems I've encountered are radically unevenly sized gzip'ed text input files.  Gzip'ed files can't be split, so each one ends up being a single partition.  A fix for this situation is fairly easy: just call "repartition" to evenly reshuffle the data after it's read --- "sc.textFile(input).repartition(10000)".

Sometimes the problem is that some keys are radically more popular than others.  Not much that can be done here, except going back to the drawing board to rethink another way to key the data.

When using "sortByKey", Spark "guesses" at a good range-partitioning scheme by taking a sample of the data.  It can end up being very wrong, resulting in very unevenly sized partitions.  The solution I've used in this situation is to come up with my own custom range-partitioning scheme, and use the "repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions" call.

So the fix might be as easy as calling "repartition", or painful --- writing custom and possibly complex partitioning code and calling "partitionBy" or its cousins.